# DeprecationWarning is not raised on import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completely at lost about what is happening here.

I have a `foo.py` module looking like:

```py
import warnings

def user_warn():
    warnings.warn('user_warn', UserWarning)

def depr_warn():
    warnings.warn('depr_warn', DeprecationWarning)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    user_warn()
    depr_warn()
```

If I run this with python3 (3.8.5):

```
$ python3 foo.py 
foo.py:4: UserWarning: user_warn
  warnings.warn('user_warn', UserWarning)
foo.py:7: DeprecationWarning: depr_warn
  warnings.warn('depr_warn', DeprecationWarning)
```

So far, so good. Now, let's add a `bar.py` module in the same folder:

```py
import foo

foo.user_warn()
foo.depr_warn()
```

I'd expect both warnings to be raised again. But it's not the case:

```
$ python3 bar.py 
/home/mowglie/tmp/warnings/foo.py:4: UserWarning: user_warn
  warnings.warn('user_warn', UserWarning)
```

What is happening here?

Comment: When I run `python foo.py`, I only get the UserWarning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [default warning filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filter) look like this:

```
default::DeprecationWarning:__main__
ignore::DeprecationWarning
ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning
ignore::ImportWarning
ignore::ResourceWarning
```

The first two lines mean that `DeprecationWarning` is ignored by default in any module other than `__main__`.

Comment: Thanks! I got to this right after sending my question as always. So if I am the developer of `foo.py`: how do I warn my users to not use the deprecated functions?

Comment: Ha! This helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377831/difference-between-deprecationwarning-pendingdeprecationwarning-and-futurewarni -> I need to change my DeprecationWarnings to FutureWarnings

Comment: @Fabzi: Those are intended for end users, not other developers. If your warning is intended for developers, you're supposed to use DeprecationWarning and just hope that people test their code with warnings enabled.